# How to delete a redux store by key name

Tags: redux, redux-persist

I have configured my main store in redux persist like this:

```
const persistConfig = {
   key: 'v1.0',
   storage: AsyncStorage,
};
```

Now I have changed the store ***key name***, as I found out I can use `version` instead to version my store and structure.

It became this:

```
const persistConfig = {
   key: 'root',
   version: 2,
   storage: AsyncStorage,
   migrate: createMigrate(migrations, { debug: false }),
};
```

My problem is that the previous store `key: 'v1.0'` is still available and I can access it if I change the key name back to it. **How can I clear all data on that store and just remove it?**

Comment: I guess you can handle it in your reducer with some condition check like `if (storedKey !== payload.value.key) { clearState }`

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I found until now that seem to work.
Assign the old store before the new one and use the method Purge().

```js
/***** OLD STORE PURGING ******/
const persistConfigOld = {
   key: 'v1.0',
   storage: AsyncStorage,
};
const persistedReducerOld = persistReducer(persistConfigOld, rootReducer)
const oldStore = createStore(
  persistedReducerOld,
);
//purge
const purge = (store) => {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            // Purge RAM cached reducer states
            store.dispatch({ type: "RESET" });
            // Purge disk cached reducer states
            const persistor = persistStore(store, {},
                (err) => {
                    if (err)
                        reject(err);
                    resolve();
                }
            );
            persistor.purge();
        }
    );
};
purge(oldStore);
/***** END OLD STORE PURGING ******/
```

Found [here](https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline/issues/203#issuecomment-377742370).